# How to reduce Grails' reload check interval

Tags: grails, reloading

Whenever I touch (save) a groovy class, in Grails development mode, there's a noticeable interval (around 10 seconds) before I start seeing `Compiling 1 source files` messages.

Is there a setting to reduce (speed up) the interval between checks?

Is there a way to make it ring the terminal bell (beep) when the reloading is done?

Answer (score 0):

Put a development copy of your project repository in a ramdisk (but always remember to commit and push your modifications!).

This will practically zero your disk access time, since it won't be accessing the disk at all (mostly).

Comment: I'll try that, but I believe the problem is the check interval that is set too high, not the actual disk access.